# Azure DevOps pipeline stuck

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am facing below error while i am running the pipeline.

This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-Hosted Private'. Current position in queue: 1

Note: This is my first job and i am not running any additional pipelines in the same project.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Muthu Kumar M.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can view in-progress jobs in **Parallel jobs** of Organization Settings to check if there is only one running job.

[image]

If your organization is newly created, there could be no agent pool available.

Since March, we have temporarily disabled the free grant of parallel jobs for public projects and for certain private projects in new organizations. However, you can request this grant by sending an email to azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com.

[Related release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-183-update#change-in-process-for-obtaining-free-pipelines-grant-in-public-projects)

For more information about parallel jobs and free grants, see our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?preserve-view=true&tabs=ms-hosted&view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks for the information but didn't get any response from azpipelines-ossgrant@microsoft.com

Comment: You can try the email: azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?preserve-view=true&tabs=ms-hosted&view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own private build server to overcome this limit.